# Maven and env vars from file

Tags: maven, environment-variables, maven-plugin

I switched to maven and have a question. I use env file with vars for development, which is loaded to intellij idea via envfile. For deployment I use docker with another env file for container deployment. I switch these files via maven profiles.
But the problem is, that I cannot load these settings to maven, mostly for testing, for example for local build or some automated deployment.
My question - is there a way, like plugin or something, to load env file from maven? I made a makefile, but don't think it's a good idea really. I found apache surefire but looks like it cannot do what i need, or i simply didn't realise how to configure.

Thank you

Comment: First what kind of things you put in your env files.. as you wrote for testing... in which way ? Via Java ? Frameworks or alike?

Comment: just variables. like DB_NAME=db, DB_USER=user, IAM_HOST=iamhost.com and so on

Comment: @khmarbaise sorry, not sure i understand your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`properties-maven-plugin`](https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/).

With this plugin you can define a default config file and multiple override files that you can choose from.  For example its configuration could be

```
<configuration>
    <quiet>true</quiet>
    <files>
        <file>env.properties</file>
        <file>env_${user.name}.properties</file>
    </files>
</configuration>
```

In this way the overrride files could be, for example:

1. `env_myUserName.properties`
2. `env_production.properties`
3. `env_jboss.properties`

The first one, if present, will be used automatically assuming that `myUserName` is your OS user (per-developer configuration), the other ones can be enabled from the command line with the well known `-Duser.name=` parameter.  For example:

```
mvn clean install -Duser.name=production
```

Comment: Well, although it's not what Im looking for, your answer helped me to understand how I should organise my project. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, but, what else are you looking for?  The plugin loads an env in Maven and lets you switch the env from cmd line.

Comment: I have seen your new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76987507/spring-application-properties-docker-and-tests and now I understand that you were more interested in Spring properties than Maven properties.

Comment: yep, when I realized it, I understood the answer ) anyway, it’s easy to achieve with gradle and i still suppose that ‘reading env from the file’ approach is more consistent. Anyway, it’s working now, thank you!