# Spring application.properties, docker and tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, environment-variables

I use spring boot app with maven and i need to set spring properties and I cannot sort it out.

Problem:

Assume, there's a spring app and application.properties should have `spring.datasource.url` set.

I have two maven profiles with two different application.properties files, one for development and second one for deployment. Like, application-container.properties and application-dev.properties:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>container</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>container</activatedProperties>
                <spring.profiles.active>container</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

and application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
```

- For development and testing it should be something like

application-dev.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc://devdatabase://localhost:12345/database
```

- The app built should run in container, suppose it is docker. For docker application.properties will look like

application-container.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=${DATASOURCE}
```

And in docker the env file will be used, like (docker-compose.yaml):

```
    env_file:
      - ./docker.env
```

where docker.env is like:

```
DATASOURCE=jdbc://proddatabase://prodhost:2345/proddatabase
```

The problem is, that when I build app locally for docker deployment, I cannot run tests because `spring.datasource.url` is expected to be set from the system environment. I tried to find a maven plugin to load env variables from file(s) but didn't succeed.

Worth to mention, that I actually have like 20-30 such a parameters.

My question: how could I solve that? I'm not familiar with maven yet, maybe there's another approach I could use except building in the container? Ideally i'd like to use single application.properties that takes values from the environment and just switch the environment for maven by using different env files, like it's done in docker. It will be great to see some example as well.

Your advices are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use the spring.profiles.active?
You can define a variable in your different environment.
Make three properties file in your code.
One is application.properties,
it just set spring.profiles.active = ${Your environment variable name}
The other two is container.properties and dev.properties,define the different environment variable.
Then set the different variable in your develop operate system and your container system.

Comment: Thank you for reply! Your help is greatly appreciated, but I'm not sure I understand it. I do use spring profiles. The problem is, that I need to set vars from env for container, but cannot test outside container because env vars ain't set in maven

Comment: I added application.properties for clarification

Comment: Well, at last I got your idea. Brilliant! Thank you!